# Algorithm input in a box

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I am trying to write pseudo code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand\INPUT{\item[\algorithmicinput]}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicoutput{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand\OUTPUT{\item[\algorithmicinput]}

\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for each}}
\newcommand{\INDSTATE}[1][1]{\STATE\hspace{#1\algorithmicindent}}



\def\ForEach{\ForAll}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My Algorithm}{ }
\begin{algorithmic}[1]


\INPUT  
\Statex a , \Comment The a of the algo
\Statex $b$  \Comment The b of the algo ,

\Statex $c$  \Comment The c of the algo 

\noindent \Statex  \hrulefill
\State $V \gets 0$


    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    \end{document}
```

1. I want the `\INPUT` to be in a box or somehow surrounded in a border
2. Currently I just added an horizontal line, but it is indented, is there a way to remove the indentation?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: I noticed a small mistake in your code: `\algnewcommand\OUTPUT{\item[\algorithmicinput]}` should be `\algnewcommand\OUTPUT{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use TikZ and `\tikzmark` for this: first, using `\tikzmark` you place a mark right after `\INPUT` and another one right where your inputs end, and then use the `\DrawBox` command with those two marks to draw the frame; the optional argument allows you to control some attributes (color, line width) of the frame:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=2pt] (#1) {};}
\newcommand\DrawBox[3][]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\draw[#1] ([xshift=-3.5em,yshift=7pt]#2.north west) rectangle (#3.south east);}

\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand\INPUT{\item[\algorithmicinput]}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Expand $K$- Plex}{ }
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Statex
\INPUT\tikzmark{a}  
\Statex $a$ \Comment The a of the algo
\Statex $b$  \Comment The b of the algo
\Statex $c$  \Comment The c of the algo\tikzmark{b}
\State $V \gets 0$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\DrawBox{a}{b}
    
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Expand $K$- Plex}{ }
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Statex
\INPUT\tikzmark{c}  
\Statex $a$ \Comment The a of the algo
\Statex $b$  \Comment The b of the algo
\Statex $c$  \Comment The c of the algo\tikzmark{d}
\State $V \gets 0$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\DrawBox[cyan]{c}{d}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code needs three runs to stabilize.

In a comment it has been requested to have a background color for the frame; this can be easily achieved using the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library (the library provides a sophisticated version of `\tikzmark`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\newcommand\DrawBox[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[overlay,fill=gray!30,#1] 
    ([xshift=-3.7em,yshift=2.1ex]{pic cs:#2}) 
    rectangle 
    ([xshift=2pt,yshift=-0.7ex]pic cs:#3);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand\INPUT{\item[\algorithmicinput]}

\begin{document}

\DrawBox{a}{b}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Expand $K$- Plex}{ }
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Statex
\INPUT\tikzmark{a}  
\Statex $a$ \Comment The a of the algo
\Statex $b$  \Comment The b of the algo
\Statex $c$  \Comment The c of the algo\tikzmark{b}
\Statex
\State $V \gets 0$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\DrawBox[draw=orange,fill=orange!30]{c}{d}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Expand $K$- Plex}{ }
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Statex
\INPUT\tikzmark{c}  
\Statex $a$ \Comment The a of the algo
\Statex $b$  \Comment The b of the algo
\Statex $c$  \Comment The c of the algo\tikzmark{d}
\Statex
\State $V \gets 0$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Some remarks:

1. The library provides a sophisticated version of `\tikzmark`, so there's no need to define it once the library has been loaded.
2. The `\DrawBox` command must be used *before* the algorithm to which it will be applied; otherwise, the background will overwrite the contents of the input.
3. Two or three runs are necessary for the code to stabilize.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this works perfectly. Is there a way to add a background to the box? lets say gray background?

Comment: @user844541 You're welcome! Please see my updated answer for a solution allowing you to add a background color.

Comment: how do i make the box always fill up to the right. i removed comment and the box got reduced in size