# highlight sections of algorithm

Tags: algorithm2e

I am trying to have sections of my algorithm highlighted like the figure below. I am using algorithm2e on sharedlatex. Is there a simple solution ?

[image]

Comment: Could you add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))?

Comment: See: [Algorithm input in a box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155679/124842). Use it with  `draw=none` ->`\DrawBox[draw=none,fill=orange!30]{c}{d}`.

Comment: for the solution at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149779/how-can-i-colourfuly-highlight-some-lines-of-an-algorithm-using-algorithm2e , how do i have the highlight fill up the left margin ?